# Cancellable task with IHostedService and start/stop from outside the service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0, ihostedservice

I have a single `IHostedService` in my app. It starts *a Discord chat bot* and a *trading bot* which proceeds realtime data. Both of them are started once the application loads (`IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted`).

The Discord chat bot is being started into a separate thread, because it has to be alive during the entire app. It's supposed to control the trading bot. I mean the user can send commands like /startbot, /stopbot, /help, etc.

The trading bot is the main logic of the app. It basically connects to Binance web socket streams and processes realtime data.

#### Questions

1. When I do `Ctrl + C`, OnStopping gets executed but it never reaches OnStopped or stops the application, because `ITradeManager.Run` is running an infinite loop.

**Note: The reason I didn't use a BackgroundService, is because these ITradeManager and IDiscordCommandHandler should be started once the application loads (`IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted`).**

```
OnStarted has been called.

[2021-02-28 00:41:49 Information] ElonMuskBot.Discord.DiscordCommandHandler
DiscordCommandHandler is starting.

[2021-02-28 00:41:49 Information] ElonMuskBot.Discord.DiscordCommandHandler
[Discord.NET - Discord] Discord.Net v2.3.0-dev-20210121.1 (API v6)

[2021-02-28 00:41:49 Information] ElonMuskBot.Discord.DiscordCommandHandler
[Discord.NET - Gateway] Connecting

[2021-02-28 00:41:50 Information] ElonMuskBot.Discord.DiscordCommandHandler
[Discord.NET - Gateway] Connected

[2021-02-28 00:41:51 Information] ElonMuskBot.Discord.DiscordCommandHandler
[Discord.NET - Gateway] Ready

[2021-02-28 00:41:51 Information] ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager
Test

[2021-02-28 00:41:52 Information] ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager
Test

[2021-02-28 00:41:52 Information] ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager
Test

[2021-02-28 00:41:52 Information] ElonMuskBot.BotHostedService
OnStopping has been called.

[2021-02-28 00:41:53 Information] ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager
Test

[2021-02-28 00:41:53 Information] ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager
Test

[2021-02-28 00:41:54 Information] ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager
Test

[2021-02-28 00:41:54 Information] ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager
Test
```

2. I want to be able to start/stop the `ITradeManager.Run` from outside and more specifically from the [BotControlModule](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/commands/dependency-injection.html#example---injection-in-modules):

```cs
public class BotControlModule : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("start")]
    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        await ReplyAsync("Bot has started.");
    }

    [Command("forcebuy", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
    public async Task ForceBuy(string pair)
    {
        await ReplyAsync("Forcebuy executed");
    }
}
```

#### Snippet

```cs
services.AddSingleton(new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig { LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info }));
services.AddSingleton(new CommandService(new CommandServiceConfig { LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info }));
services.AddSingleton<IDiscordCommandHandler, DiscordCommandHandler>();

services.AddSingleton<LiveTradeManager>();
services.AddSingleton<BacktestTradeManager>();
services.AddSingleton<ITradeManagerFactory, TradeManagerFactory>();
```

```cs
public class BotHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<BotHostedService> _logger;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;
    private readonly IDiscordCommandHandler _handler;
    private readonly ITradeManager _tradeManager;

    public BotHostedService(
        ILogger<BotHostedService> logger,
        IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime,
        IDiscordCommandHandler commandHandler,
        ITradeManagerFactory tradeManagerFactory,
        IOptions<ExchangeOptions> options)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _appLifetime = appLifetime;
        _handler = commandHandler;
        _tradeManager = tradeManagerFactory.GetTradeManager(options.Value.TradeManagerType);
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _handler.StopAsync();
    }

    private void OnStarted()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnStarted has been called.");

        Task.Run(async () => await _handler.StartAsync());

        // TODO: This one is still running after we close the app
        _tradeManager.Run();
    }

    private void OnStopping()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnStopping has been called.");
    }

    private void OnStopped()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnStopped has been called.");
    }
}

public class LiveTradeManager : ITradeManager
{
    private readonly ILogger<LiveTradeManager> _logger;
    private readonly IClient _client;

    public LiveTradeManager(
        ILogger<LiveTradeManager> logger, IOptions<ExchangeOptions> options, IClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _client = clientFactory.GetClient(options.Value.ClientType);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Test");

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}

public class DiscordCommandHandler : IDiscordCommandHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<DiscordCommandHandler> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly IOptions<DiscordOptions> _discordOptions;
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly CommandService _commands;

    public DiscordCommandHandler(
        ILogger<DiscordCommandHandler> logger,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IOptions<DiscordOptions> discordOptions,
        DiscordSocketClient client,
        CommandService commands)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _discordOptions = discordOptions;
        _client = client;
        _commands = commands;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("DiscordCommandHandler is starting.");

        _client.Ready += ReadyAsync;
        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
        _client.Log += LogAsync;

        _commands.CommandExecuted += CommandExecutedAsync;
        _commands.Log += LogAsync;

        await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), _serviceProvider).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_discordOptions.Value.Token))
        {
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _discordOptions.Value.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await _client.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    public async Task StopAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("DiscordCommandHandler is stopping.");

        await _client.SetStatusAsync(UserStatus.Offline).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _client.SetGameAsync(null).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _client.StopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        _client.Ready -= ReadyAsync;
        _client.MessageReceived -= HandleCommandAsync;
        _client.Log -= LogAsync;

        _commands.CommandExecuted -= CommandExecutedAsync;
        _commands.Log -= LogAsync;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

> When I do Ctrl + C, OnStopping gets executed but it never reaches OnStopped or stops the application, because ITradeManager.Run is running an infinite loop.

To cancel code, first define a `CancellationTokenSource`. Pass the `CancellationToken` into the running code (`ITradeManager.Run`), and observe the token there (i.e., either pass the token to another method like `Task.Delay`, or periodically call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`). Then, when your cancellation is requested (i.e., `ApplicationStopping`), cancel the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Side note: `BackgroundService` does this for you. I'm not sure why you couldn't use it.

> I want to be able to start/stop/pause the ITradeManager.Run from outside and more specifically from the BotControlModule

You'll need to have a synchronization primitive for this, e.g., `ManualResetEvent` (or `AsyncManualResetEvent`). Have your code (i.e., `ITradeManager.Run`) periodically wait for this event to be set. When a pause request comes in, reset the event, and when a resume request comes in, set the event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I couldn't use BackgroundService because I want to make sure the application is loaded, before I initialize IDiscordCommandHandler and ITradeManager. The `is loaded` part I'm achieving with IHostApplicationLifetime. I will try it now and send back code

Comment: this is what I did. The first part seems to be working, but I don't know how to implement the ManualResetEvent. https://pastebin.com/9KUfB59v. Could you please provide an example? You can use something similar to mine. It's not such a big code anyway

Comment: I'd recommend using `BackgroundService` - you can just inject `IHostApplicationLifetime` and pause your main loop until the host is loaded. For the MRE, you'd probably want to wrap it up into a type that exposes `WaitIfPaused()`, `Pause()` and `Resume()` methods, and register that type as a singleton. `WaitIfPaused() => _mre.Wait();`, `Pause() => _mre.Reset();`, `Resume() => _mre.Set();`

Comment: By the way, I edited the question. All I need is /start /stop functionality, but I kinda don't understand the way that it should work. That's why I wanted a code example.

Comment: @nop: My last comment has the code you should need. If that's not clear, you could ask another question specifically regarding pause/resume behavior.